# Varchar and nvarchar datatype sizes

Tags: sql-server

I have an issue on SQL Server 2016 where the documentation about `varchar` and `nvarchar` is not correct for my database. I just can't figure out what is the special case that I have.

I have a table with a primary key and a `varchar(2000)` column with a couple million rows for a total of exactly `2,320,096` kilobytes used space. Converting from `varchar(2000)` to `nvarchar(2000)` for unicode support, I see a reduction in size to `2,307,520` kilobytes.

Why is that happening?

From the documentation it says `varchar` take n + 2 bytes and a `nvarchar` should be 2 * n + 2. To me I was expecting doubling the size of my data but I got a decrease.

I know a smaller size is not a negative thing although this raise question about if there is actual issues. Also the index size grows while it remained unchanged.

Edit with aftermath of full backup and reindex of the test database :
changing `int` to `tinyint` or `Datetime` to `date` which per documentation should reduce size are also in fact increasing the db size.

More actual data :
Changing 1 column (not the indexed column) from `int` to `tinyint` grow the space used by 9% and increase the index size by 5%

Changing 1 column (not the indexed column) from `datetime` to `date` grow the space used by 7% and increase the index size by 4%

Comment: Your existing data might have been quite fragmented, with lots of empty space on pages. Changing the type forces a rebuild. It's also possible your table (or index) has compression applied, either row or page, in which case the difference would also mostly disappear.

Comment: What was the collation of the original `varchar` column? It's possible that the original `varchar` column was using a multibyte collation and contained lots of international characters that could be stored more efficiently by `nvarchar` - which uses UCS-2 encoding by default, or UTF-16 encoding when using a *_SC (supplementary characters) collation.

Comment: Also if the table is compressed, the nvarchar columns will use Unicode Compression: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-compression/unicode-compression-implementation?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: @AlwaysLearning The `nvarchar` column does not contain a single unicode char. They are all 255 and lower.

Comment: The total size of the database would typically increase because rebuilding an index keeps the old index around while the rebuild is happening. A backup will backup all pages in the database, even if those pages are no longer in use. The size of the new index should be smaller than the old one, but your database would not become smaller unless you shrink it with a reorganize (which is not recommended, however, due to the fragmentation this can cause). If you check `sp_spaceused`, you should find the size in use has gone down, and the freed pages will be used for new data before the DB grows.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Yeah but actually no, i use `sp_spacedused` and just check the used space and not the total and the used space is growing when i reduce the field size

Comment: Well that's extremely odd, counterintuitive, and I'd almost say impossible, but I like to keep that word around only for emergencies. :P I cannot reproduce your finding, in any case -- creating a table with an `INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY` and an `INT` column and filling it with 100K rows gives a table that takes up 1736 KB reserved space. Changing the second column to a `TINYINT` and rebuilding the clustered index results in a table that takes up 1480 KB space. Did you verify your table isn't compressed?

Comment: @JeroenMostert Well the property `Compression Type` on the table mention `None` so i would assume it mean there is no compression unless something weird is happening here. What about if the DB files themselves are on a VM and the IT have compressed the drives behind the scene ? Not saying that's the case as i would have to check with IT what they did. Would that explain my gain of size when i try to decrease my datatype.

Comment: That confirms your table's clustered index is not compressed; individual indexes may still be compressed but that would be unusual. Have you done an `ALTER INDEX ALL ON [table] REBUILD`? An `ALTER COLUMN` on its own will not compact the index. If all that should fail, the only remaining thing I can think of to check is whether the `FILLFACTOR` and `PAD_INDEX` options have been changed from their defaults (`0` and `OFF`, respectively), which is not generally recommended but occasionally done by people who *think* they know what those options do.

Comment: And no, virtual storage has zero influence on the results of `sp_spaceused`, as that only counts (logical) pages in use as seen by SQL Server, regardless of the physical space those pages may or may not occupy.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I did not alter index. I am really running 3 queries per column. I delete the constraint which is a default value, then alter the datatype, then recreate the constraint and that's it. Nothing fancy. I do it by query as using the GUI with that many record it just freeze and die.

Comment: In my little experiment, explicitly rebuilding the indexes was necessary to free up any actual pages; an `ALTER TABLE` on its own was not enough. Likely the engine does rewrite all the rows, but doesn't compact the (clustered) index while it's at it.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Unfortunately I had full backup followed by reindex on Sunday morning and this morning since the last changes and numbers did not change. I think I'll need to get in touch with Microsoft SQL Specialist as this makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end we got in touch with a MSSQL specialist and we learned that the rebuild index task in maintenance plan does not actually rebuild index despite the name. He made us run the simple manual rebuild query and that actually rebuild the index and the table size shrunk by up to 80%